# An abstract input verifier and the JDialog class

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to understand a class I came across [here](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t20551.html) to validate input on a few JTextAreas I have. I've got it working fine, but I'm confused as to some of the logic, with specific reference to the use of a JDialog as a parent component and hoped someone could help me understand it better.

The Abstract validator class:

```
package gui;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.InputVerifier;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;

public abstract class AbstractValidator extends InputVerifier implements KeyListener{

private JDialog popup;
private Object parent;
private JLabel messageLabel;
private JLabel image;
private Point point;
private Dimension cDim;
private Color color;

private AbstractValidator(){
    color = new Color(243,255,159);
}

private AbstractValidator(JComponent c, String msg){
    this();
    c.addKeyListener(this);
    messageLabel = new JLabel(msg + " ");
    //image = new JLabel();         
}

public AbstractValidator(JDialog parent, JComponent c, String msg){
    this(c,msg);
    this.parent = parent;
    popup = new JDialog(parent);
    initComponents();
}

//implement the actual validation logic, returning false if the data is 
//invalid and true if it is not. you can also set the popup msg text with
//setMessage() before returning.
//param c is the component to be validated

protected abstract boolean validationCriteria(JComponent c);

//this method is called by Java when a component needs to be validated. 
//it should not be called directly. Don't override this unless you want to change
//validation behaviour. implement validationCriteria() instead.

@Override
public boolean verify(JComponent c){
    if(!validationCriteria(c)){
        if(parent instanceof Validatable)
            ((Validatable)parent).validateFailed();

        c.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
        popup.setSize(0,0);
        popup.setLocationRelativeTo(c);
        point = popup.getLocation();
        cDim = c.getSize();
        popup.setLocation(point.x-(int)cDim.getWidth()/2, point.y+(int)cDim.getHeight()/2);
        popup.pack();
        popup.setVisible(true);
        return false;
    }
    c.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));
    if(parent instanceof Validatable)
        ((Validatable)parent).validatePassed();
    return true;
}

protected void setMessage(String msg){
    messageLabel.setText(msg);   
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    popup.setVisible(false);
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
}
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){}

private void initComponents(){
    popup.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    popup.setUndecorated(true);
    popup.getContentPane().setBackground(color);
    popup.getContentPane().add(messageLabel);
    popup.setFocusableWindowState(false);

}
}
```

The concrete class:

```
package gui;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class NotEmptyValidator extends AbstractValidator{
    public NotEmptyValidator(JDialog parent, JTextField c, String msg){
        super(parent,c, msg);
    }

    protected boolean validationCriteria(JComponent c){
        if(((JTextField)c).getText().equals("")){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The (unused) interface:

```
package gui;

public interface Validatable {
    void validateFailed();
    void validatePassed();
}
```

The use of the concrete class on a JTextField in the main JPanel:

```
textField.setInputVerifier(new NotEmptyValidator(new JDialog(), textField, "msg"));
```

Firstly (but unimportantly) I'm confused as to why the author has separated the constructors in the abstract class? I don't think it particularly matters though.

As mentioned though, I'm more confused about the use of a JDialog thoughout.
From the description in the above link, and the code that uses instanceof and then calls the interface methods, it looks like it is used to manipulate other components when first verify() is called (by java) followed by the implemented method 'validationCriteria()'.

But it's the fact that it's a JDialog that confuses me, why wouldn't it just be a JComponent? I think I'm missing some fundamental knowledge here - which is why my instantiation of the concrete class just uses a 'new' JDialog - although I am going to be reading the oracle trail on inputverifier because I think some of this class design might be a bit overkill too....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As mentioned though, I'm more confused about the use of a JDialog thoughout. From the description in the above link, and the code that uses instanceof and then calls the interface methods, it looks like it is used to manipulate other components when first verify() is called (by java) followed by the implemented method 'validationCriteria()'.

They seem to using the `JDialog` (or `JFrame`) as a reference point for their own internal `JDialog` which is used to display a message when the validation fails. This is an (optional) requirement for the `JDialog` which allows it to be placed over the parent window from which it's been called

Based on the example code, I'd say they are simply cheating and while I've not tested it, you could pass `null` (but you'd have to cast it to either `JDialog` or `JFrame`)

The may also be a little old (or they aren't aware of some the additional API functionality) as they could use `setLocationRelativeTo` instead of manually positioning the dialog

Getting into the nitty gritty, `validationCriteria` is where you supply the validation for the component, this is, as you've described, called by `verify`. This provides means by which the author can take control of the validation process and implement their customisations.  Remember `c` is a reference to the `JComponent` which you are trying to validate (ie the `JTextArea`)

The author provides additional customisation in the form of `WantsValidationStatus`, which can be implemented by the `parent` (`JDialog` or `JFrame`) which provides a means of notification about the state of the validation process

> Firstly (but unimportantly) I'm confused as to why the author has separated the constructors in the abstract class? I don't think it particularly matters though.

My guess is, they want to provide a flexible arrangement, but don't understand some of the features which the Swing API provides, for example.  You could reduce the number of constructors to 1 and use [`SwingUtilities#windowForComponent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#windowForComponent-java.awt.Component-) to obtain a reference to the window which contains the component

> But it's the fact that it's a JDialog that confuses me, why wouldn't it just be a JComponent? I think I'm missing some fundamental knowledge here - which is why my instantiation of the concrete class just uses a 'new' JDialog - although I am going to be reading the oracle trail on inputverifier because I think some of this class design might be a bit overkill too....

Well, pretty much the other two comments should have answered that by now :P

## Parting thoughts

To my mind, this is slightly wrong. I'd not have any components passed to the class via the constructor, it's not it's responsibility to be displaying messages or taking additional action, it's job is simply to validate the component and return `true`/`false` (which then controls the focus transversal).

To my mind, it'd be better for the `InputVerifier` to support an observer pattern, which then generates `validationFailed`/`validationPassed` (or such) events and let some other delegate make the decisions about what should be done, but that's ;)

Comment: thanks for the indepth answer.

yeah my main confusion was about the notification of the validation process that you described, rather than the JDialog validation fail message. sorry I missed that the popup variable was also a JDialog so wasn't particularly clear.

I agree that I'm not sure that this approach is ideal and that he was trying to create a flexible/reusable class and overcomplicated things. So I'm going to go and study InputVerifier a little more and see if I can come up with something similar to what you describe. Thanks again.